# How can I backup the whole system status (not documents)?

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup, system-settings, etc

I want to backup my system status, like

- Installed Packeges
- What's on my sidebar
- Grub Settings
- Kernel...

in order to restore it in case of system crash.

I don't care about my document, music, files (`/home`, I suppose).

What directories do I have to select in the backup apart from `/etc`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a system image which store all your data and program with `dd` (disk dump)

for example you can backup your system partition by running

```
dd if=/dev/sdxy of=bak.img bs=4M
```

x=sda,sdb,sdc,...

y=sdx1, sdx2,...

or the whole harddisk include partition table, mbr, data by running this command

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=bak.img bs=4M
```

x=sda,sdb,sdc,...

and to restore the image run

```
dd if=bak.img of=/dev/sdxy bs=4M
```

or if you backup the whole system disk

```
dd if=bak.img of=/dev/sdx bs=4M
```